# Trouble Setting Intervals with Jquery & a faulty function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a javascript document, using Jquery, where I am trying to cycle through an array of colors as my background while managing the alpha value separately. The "setColor" function works perfectly fine however the "manageAlpha" function does not seem to work at all. **My goal is to set my alphaVar to the absolute value of a sin function in increasing increments of PI/10 with a .15 second interval.** I cannot figure out this issue! Please help!

```
var backgroundCol = new Array(53);
var alphaVar;

backgroundCol[0] = 'rgba(255,192,192,' + alphaVar + ')';
//(array truncated)

var colorCounter = -1;
var numberOfColors = 53;
var colorTimer;
var alphaTimer;
var sinCounter = 0;
var goingUp = true;

function setColor() {

  $('body.page1').css('background-color', (backgroundCol[colorCounter]));

  colorCounter += 1;
  if (colorCounter >= numberOfColors) {
    colorCounter = -1;
  }

}

function manageAlpha() {

  sinCounter += Math.PI / 10;
  alphaVar = abs(sin(sinCounter));
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('body.page1').css('background-color', (backgroundCol[colorCounter]));

  //colorTimer = setInterval(setColor, 150);
  alphaTimer = setInterval(manageAlpha, 150);

});
```

Comment: Well the first problem I see is on line 3 you use the alphaVar variable without having assigned a value to it. The second is that you use colorCounter as an array index when its value is -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, in order to use use the absolute value and sin functions, use `Math.abs()` and `Math.sin()`:

```
function manageAlpha() {
    sinCounter += Math.PI / 10;
    alphaVar = Math.abs(Math.sin(sinCounter));
}
```

Then, the other issue is that the values in the `backgroundCol` array will not update themselves automatically when `alphaVar` is changed. When you define

```
backgroundCol[0] = 'rgba(255,192,192,' + alphaVar + ')';
```

the value of `alphaVar` is undefined, so `backgroundCol[0]` is the string `"rgba(255,192,192,undefined)"`, even if the value of `alphaVar` changes later.

What you can do is leave alpha out of the `backgroundCol` array and add it in when you call `.css()`.

So something like:

```
backgroundCol[0] = 'rgba(255,192,192,';

function setColor() {
    $('body.page1').css('background-color', backgroundCol[colorCounter] + alphaVar + ')'); 
}
```